# Where can i delete my react Temporary files in my macOs?

Tags: macos, react-native, watchman

I've tried those 2 bellow, and look in the /tmp files but these folders doesn't exist

rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*

The watchman watch-del-all

Remove node_modules npm install isn't solving the error and the deletion of the tmp is the suggestion i can't get working

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but if you open terminal and type 'echo $TMPDIR' you'll get the path to the metro and react cache folders.